# What exactly does "const" guarantee?

Tags: c++

Example:

```cpp
int main() 
{
    int some_int = 10;
    int other_int = 11;
    const int * ptr = &some_int;
    ptr = &other_int; // Not allowed!
}
```

The above is expected, but this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int some_int = 10;
    const int * ptr = &some_int;
    // *ptr = 11; // Not allowed!
    some_int = 11; // Allowed! Has same effect.
}
```

Why does `const` care about what is written in the memory the `ptr` *points to*?

> C++ supports two notions of immutability:
> • const: meaning roughly ‘‘I promise not to change this value.’’ This is used primarily to
> specify interfaces so that data can be passed to functions using pointers and references without fear of it being modified. The compiler enforces the promise made by const. The value
> of a const can be calculated at run time. ...

"the compiler enforces the promise", what exactly does it enforce?
I can still freely manipulate the memory that's pointed at.
Does compiler only truly enforce the pointer's value?

Comment: You're confusing "mutable-pointer to a const-value" and "const-pointer to a mutable-value". See the linked question.

Comment: The first example that says `// Not allowed!`, the comment is mistaken; it is allowed.

Comment: @Eljay are you sure? It clearly says:


 error: assignment of read-only location ‘* ptr’
   15 |     *ptr = 11; // Not allowed!
      |     ~~~~~^~~~

Comment: In the first example, `ptr = &other_int; // Not allowed!`

Comment: Wow, *now* I'm curious. I didn't notice that. Why is that? O.o

Comment: I used the spiral rule and now it makes perfect sense. It's the data that is a constant not the pointer itself. I should have written `const int * const ptr` for that one.
Thanks!

Comment: _What exactly does “const” guarantee?_  It means the programmer guarantees that the object marked `const` will not be modified in the context of the `const` and is thread-safe (either logically const or physically const).  It does not mean the language guarantees it; the language has some checks to help enforce it.